# Geforce 368.69 driver installation on Windows won't work and ends in black screen

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, installation, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

I've downloaded and attempted installation of the Geforce 368.69 driver both as the standalone and via Geforce Experience, done also on fresh installs of windows 10 AND windows 8.1 (mainly because I became fed up with Windows 10)

The installer works and the loading bar gets to the end before the system freezes and displays only a black screen (which requires me to hold the power button down to restart the PC). The same went for my attempts through Windows 10

I've tried using DDU to uninstall any trace of Windows Update's drivers for the graphics card (a GTX 670 that has been working fine) but to no avail

upon reboot into Windows 8.1 NVIDIA does not show up in control panel programs list despite my running of the installer

how may I get my GPU up and running with a working driver?